# Error obtaining device screen shots : unable to connect to adb. Check if adb is installed correctly

Tags: android, appium

Hi I am facing a issue that while click on Device screenshot button on UI Automator Viewer. I am getting an error message that "unable to connect to adb. Check if adb is installed correctly." I have attached my bash_profile file also

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCu24.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ojPBg.png)